# Jenkins Git plugin is not expanding environement variables

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins job to verify my pull requests with [Bitbucket Push and Pull request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request/) plugin.

The branch and commit get correctly detected but when fetching sources Jenkins git plugin fails to expand the environment variable set in the branches-to-build` field.

The documentation states clearly that an environment variable could be used to specify the branch name or pattern.

Bitbucket push and pull request plugin already provides a variable the pull request branch.

```
BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH
    Source branch - only for pull requests (BB Cloud and BB Server).
```

[image: jenkins git configuration]

Here is the Error that i get when i push my commit. You can see that the commit is correctly detected but the environment variable is not expanded or resolved.

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/${BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH}:refs/remotes/origin/${BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH}" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH}

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2102)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:366)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:197)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.ReadTrustedStep$Execution.run(ReadTrustedStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.ReadTrustedStep$Execution.run(ReadTrustedStep.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate2(ACL.java:449)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:461)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried with `${GIT_BRANCH}` as well but got the same issue.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you get the same error when you remove the curly bracket -> `$BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH`

Comment: yes. the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in **Branch Specifier**:

```
origin/${BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH}
```